# Posición Jquery UI Tooltip

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla con varios inputs juntos y utilizo el plugin Tooltip de `Jquery UI`, para mostrar un mensaje cuando los campos son obligatorios, mi problema esta en la posición de los tooltip que aparecen uno sobre otro y lo que quiero es que se vea completo cada tooltip para cada input.

Así se ve ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve leyendo la api de Position de `Jquery UI`, [option-Position](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position), pero no logro dar con la solución.

Código Js:

```
$(input).tooltip({
        content: mensaje,
        items: "input.obligatorio",
        track: true,
        show: true,
        tooltipClass: "tooltip-error"
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-5" style="height: 103px;">
     <table class="table">
          <thead class="text-center">
                                        <tr class="cabeceraDos">
                                            <th>
                                                Columna 1
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Columna 2
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Columna 3
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Columna 4
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Columna 5
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Columna 6
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Columna 7
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Columna 8
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column1"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column2"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column3"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column4"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column5"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column6"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column7"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column8"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el HTML para mostrar cómo se ejecuta? También, ¿cómo querrías solucionarlo: poniéndolos a diferentes alturas, en vertical, unos arriba y otros abajo...?

Comment: El HTML, es una tabla con los imputs en cada columna solamente, y agrego el tootip al input, si igual lo deseas ver lo agrego. La solución sería en este caso que dinamicamente queden posición vertical( arriba y abajo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar CSS para resolverlo:

Aplicando una clase mas a identificar cada celda, parecido a al estrategia de zebra en una estilo de tabla:

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio even" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column1"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control obligatorio odd" MaxLength="1" ID="txt_column2"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
....
```

Y tener dos cargas diferentes

```
$('input.even').tooltip({
        content: 'mensaje',
        items: "input.obligatorio",
        track: true,
        show: true,
        tooltipClass: "tooltip-error"
});
$('input.odd').tooltip({
        content: 'mensaje',
        items: "input.obligatorio",
        position: {
          my: "center bottom-50",
          at: "center top"
        },
        track: true,
        show: true,
        tooltipClass: "tooltip-error"
});
```

En este ejemplo se carga el tooltip un poco mas abajo. Espero te sirva

Aqui un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tn2mvzk1/)

Comment: Buena solución. Sin necesidad de añadir nuevas clases, podrías usar `td:nth-child(even) input` y `td:nth-child(odd) input` para simplificar un poco el código.

Answer (score 2):

Como indicas en la pregunta, puedes usar la opción de posición (`position`) para indicar dónde se mostrará el tooltip. La posición es un objeto que contiene diferentes valores ([fuente](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)) de los que te interesan `at` y `my`.

Una posibilidad es cambiar un poco el código para que se añade esa posición:

```
$(input).tooltip({
    content: mensaje,
    items: "input.obligatorio",
    track: true,
    show: true,
    tooltipClass: "tooltip-error",
    position: { my: "left bottom", at: "left bottom" }
});
```

Pero esto no sería suficiente porque como todos los `input` tienen el mismo valor se siguen montando unos encima de los otros. Entonces, lo que habría que hacer es cambiar un poquito más el código para que los tooltip de `input` pares se muestren en una posición, mientras que los impares se muestren en otra. Para ello:

```
$(input).each(function(index) {
    var pos = index % 2 ? "left bottom+20" : "left bottom-20";
    tooltip({
        content: mensaje,
        items: "input.obligatorio",
        track: true,
        show: true,
        tooltipClass: "tooltip-error",
        position: { my: pos, at: pos }
    });
});
```

Así se muestran a diferentes alturas (aunque aún puede que algunos se solapen). Un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var mensaje = "Complete este campo.";

  $("input").each(function(idx) {
   
    var aux = idx % 2 ? "left bottom+20" : "left bottom-20";

    $(this).tooltip({
      content: mensaje,
      items: "input.obligatorio",
      track: true,
      show: true,
      tooltipClass: "tooltip-error",
      position: { my: aux, at: aux }
    });
  });


});
```

```css
input.obligatorio {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="obligatorio"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="obligatorio"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="obligatorio"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="obligatorio"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="obligatorio"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="obligatorio"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Podrías jugar con la variable `index` para posicionar el tooltip donde quieras dependiendo de su valor. Alternativamente, también podrías crear tus propios estilos y añadirlos en `tooltipClass` dentro del `each`.